# How to trigger alert automatically in drop down list?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

For example, if I selected Volvo, then it will alert ("Volvo"), when i select Saab, it will alert("Saab")

Answer (score -1):

Select any option frome this and it will alert

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" oninput="alert(this.value)">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```